# How to remove non-UTF8 characters in RSS with Ruby

Tags: ruby, rss

I'm using Ruby's RSS Library to parse an RSS feed, but I am encountering errors occasionally when a bullet point character appears in the RSS feed as a `�`.

```
require 'rss'
rss = RSS::Parser.parse('rss_url_here', false)
```

which results in

```
#<ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8>
```

due to the `�` character. How can I remove `�` characters?

Update:

I have tried using

```
require 'net/http'
require 'rss'
uri = URI('https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/jjj?query=graphic%20design&s=100&sort=date&format=rss')
json = Net::HTTP.get(uri)

json.force_encoding('CP1252')
json.force_encoding('utf-8')

rss = RSS::Parser.parse(json, false)
```

Still getting

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

Comment: It appeared that your RSS channel provides data *not* in UTF-8 (I guess, it is CP1252.) The easiest approach would be to `File.read` the content into a string, explicitly set the string’s encoding to what it actually is (with `force_encoding`), convert it to UTF-8 with `encode` and then feed it to your parser.

Comment: Tried using your method. Updated above with what I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTMLEntities](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/)

```
HTMLEntities.new.decode(rss_feed_content)
```

Comment: Yeah, everybody likes to read text, containing accidental “&Auml;” inside.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, whether it is so hard to read a documentation on two functions I mentioned in the comment and distinguish `force_encoding` and `encode`.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'rss'
uri = URI('https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/jjj?query=graphic%20design&s=100&sort=date&format=rss')
text = Net::HTTP.get(uri)

rss = RSS::Parser.parse(text.force_encoding('CP1252').encode('utf-8'), false)
#⇒ #<RSS::RDF:0x000000053791a0 .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to remove junk char codes like this:

```
json = json.encode('UTF-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
```